# how to display plain string as date mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In my mvc application I have stored my date in string format. **eg: 10212013**

But I would like to display that sting as a date in my UI **eg: 10/21/2013**

How to archive this?? Is it possible to user `DisplayFormat` for this purpose.

**EDIT**
This is what I need to do.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => DailyTransaction.MyDate)
```

Datatype of MyDate is string so this will display as **10212013**

But I need to display this as  **10/21/2013**

can I use string format inside the view of MVC project

I tried to use the following and that is also did not work for me.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public string MyDate{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Insert two '/'s to the correct index?

Comment: If you are working with dates, you should store in a format that works better with `ToString` and `Parse`/`TryParse` so you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom DisplayFormatAttribute that will format the string in the correct format. See this [How to make configurable DisplayFormat attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576571/how-to-make-configurable-displayformat-attribute)

EDIT: After looking at your question again you could look at using an editor template to display the data: See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
YourDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For example;

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("MM/yy/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output will be;

```
10/21/2013
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/RITn0Z)</kbd>.

As an alternative, you can use [`DisplayFormatAttribute.DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:MM/yy/yyyy}")]
```

Comment: I have insert                          `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]`
`public string MyDate { get; set; }`

But nothing chage in the format

Comment: This method work only if your date is a DateTime. But yours is a string.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you just have to use insert function. here is the example

```
string dateValue = "10212013";          
string dateFormat = x.Insert(2, "/");
dateFormat = dateFormat.Insert(5, "/");
```

thats all...

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the saved format of the date you could use `Substring()` and `Format()` methods as below:

```
string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", myStringDate.Substring(0,2),
                             myStringDate.Substring(2,2),
                             myStringDate.Substring(4))
```

You can apply this to your Class and **[here is a demo](http://ideone.com/Uyybom)**;

```
public class myModelClass
{
    private string _MyDate;
    public string MyDate
    {
        get {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", _MyDate.Substring(0,2),
                                     _MyDate.Substring(2,2),
                                     _MyDate.Substring(4)); }
        set { _MyDate = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom templates for various data types that are specific to your requirements.

To create a custom template create a new file in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` - Call it `StringToDate.cshtml`.  The name is important and is used in the function call below.

Next, in the file add the code to convert the string to a date format as you require.  The simplest solution is to insert the `/` characters.

```
@model string
if (Model != null && Model.Length == 8)
{
  @(Model.Insert(2,"/").Insert(5,"/"))
} else {
  @("Err")
}
```

Add the above to the file and save it.  The else part simply outputs an error if the basic format checks fail.

Next in your view, where ever you need to display this value.  Simply use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StringDate, "StringToDate")
```