# Is there a way to customize the HTML generated by the Html.EditorFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

when I use the `Html.EditorFor` method, like this in mvc5:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RateHigh, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I get nice HTML like this:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field tarief verbruik must be a number." data-val-required="'tarief verbruik' is een verplicht veld" id="RateNormal" name="RateNormal" type="text" value="0,15">
```

Now I want to show the value with 4 decimals, and the only way I found to do that is to create an `editor template`, is that correct?

Now my question is: do I have to type all the validation attributes and the extra class names myself in an editor template (because I start from scratch)?

That looks a little unlogical because when the asp.net mvc team decides to generate different html, I must change all my editortemplates also.

So what I am looking for as a sort of 'hook' in the standard code, that I can say: I want all the html for `@Html.EditorFor`, and then format the value in 4 decimals.

Is there a way to do this?

(so what I want generated is this:
`<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field tarief verbruik must be a number." data-val-required="'tarief verbruik' is een verplicht veld" id="RateNormal" name="RateNormal" type="text" value="0,1500">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it in the model with data annotations.

Check this link out [What is the proper data annotation to format my decimal property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848969/what-is-the-proper-data-annotation-to-format-my-decimal-property)

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:#.####}")]
```

> See Custom Format Strings for formats and DisplayFormatAttribute for examples

Comment: That rocked! Is there also a possibillity to read the format string from a resource or constant (to make sure all `datformatstrings` in my viemodels are the same)?

Comment: Oh, that question was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576571/how-to-make-configurable-displayformat-attribute